# Closure of opening of closure in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

My question is somehow related to [Closure of the interior of another closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157202/closure-of-the-interior-of-another-closure)

However, I go a bit further. I have a *closed set* $X\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and $Y:=\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int} X$.

I would like to know whether $Y=\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int} Y$.

(Here, $\operatorname{cl}$ is the closure and $\operatorname{int}$ is the interior.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X, τ)$ be a topological space. We have the following: 
a.) If $F$ is closed, then $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(F)))=\operatorname{int}(F)$. 
 
b.) From (a)  you can deduce that for any open set $U$, $\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(U)))=\operatorname{cl}(U)$ 
 
if you set $U:=\operatorname{int}(X)$ you have the desired result.

$\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}X) ⊂ \operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}X \Rightarrow  \operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int}\operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}X) ⊂ \operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}X) = \operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}X,$ 
$\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int}X) ⊃ \operatorname{Int}X \Rightarrow \operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}X) ⊃ \operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Int}X) = \operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}X$

Comment: If you had a good reference to your statement that could be used in a scientific article, I would be 100% happy to accept your answer! Thanks!

Comment: I supplied the proof using a "subset" argument.
If you google this subject you will find a PDF that discusses this exact problem and they provide an identical result.  
[link](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~degt/math310_old/1997-1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks again! It seems it is quite trivial, so I'll just claim it as a fact, and if the referee complains, I'll include a proof.

Comment: @tohecz Yeah that sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $U$ is open, ie $U=U^\circ$. We have $U \subset \overline{U}$ and $\overline{U}^\circ \subset \overline{U}$. Since $U$ is open and contained in $\overline{U}$, we have $U \subset \overline{U}^\circ \subset \overline{U}$. Taking closure of both sides shows $\overline{\overline{U}^\circ} = \overline{U}$.

Now let $U = X^\circ$, $Y = \overline{U}$. Then we have $Y = \overline{Y^\circ}$.

Comment: But then $\emptyset=\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\emptyset$. Or have I overseen something?

Comment: ?????? If $X=\{x\}$ then $Y:=clint(X)=\emptyset$, and then $clint(Y)=\emptyset$=$Y$??????

Comment: You say "not in general". However, your $X$ surely satisfies my conjecture, because $Y=\emptyset$ and whence $Y=\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}Y$.

Comment: I misread the question earlier. I have answered the question as asked now!