# Closure of interior of closed set

Tags: general-topology

> If $D$ is a closed set, what is the relation in general between the set $D$ and the closure of $\operatorname{Int}D$?

We know that $\operatorname{Int}D\subseteq D$, so $\overline{\operatorname{Int}D}\subseteq \overline{D}$, but since $D$ is closed, we have $\overline{D}=D$, so that $\overline{\operatorname{Int}D}\subseteq D$.

Now, is it true as well that $D\subseteq \overline{\operatorname{Int}D}$? I can't seem to prove it, or give an example of $D$ such that this doesn't hold.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/157202/.

Comment: It is true if and only if $D$ is the closure of an open set.

Comment: For reference, sets where $D = \overline{Int D}$ are called (topologically) regular closed sets: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Regular_Closed_Set

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hint: For a counterexample, try to think of a non-empty closed set with empty interior.

Answer (score 12):

In general, the other inclusion doesn't hold.  For example, if $D = \{0\}$ is the set containing the single point 0, then its interior is empty.  There are a lot of closed sets with this property, like finite sets and Cantor sets.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\operatorname{Int}D\subseteq D$, obviously $\overline{\operatorname{Int}D}\subseteq \overline{D}=D$ holds.