# When is the interior of the closure of $A$ equal to the set $A$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We have to find a condition $B$ that make the following equivalence true:

$$B \implies {\rm int}({\rm cl}(A)) = A$$

A “valid” condition that seems to satisfy this equivalence is that there shouldn’t be a discontinuity point like for $[0, 1) \cup (1,3]$ where $1$ is the discontinuity point. But how do we translate that mathematically?

Of course $(E, d)$ is a metric space and $A$ is a subset of $E$.

The example was given on $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual distance $|x - y|$.

Comment: The condition $B$ is that we have $A\subset int(cl(A))$. Then we also have equality. See also other posts, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476217/closure-of-interior-of-closed-set). Of course, $A$ need not be a subset of a metric space in general.

Comment: Your condition $B$ will include "$A$ is an open set". To elaborate on Dietrich Burde's comment, for any open set $A$ we would have $A = \operatorname{Int}(A)\subset \operatorname{Int}(\overline{A})$. Your question would be for an open set $A$, when is $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{A})\subset A$ true?

Comment: Also see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_open_set) wikipage.

Comment: @WilliamSun I am not really following. The condition will include that A is an open set since it is equal to an interior which is open. But where does Int(A) subset of int(compliment(A)) come in? Excuse me for my markdown knowledge.

Comment: @CharbelElBateh The overline of $A$ stands for the closure of $A$, not complement.

Comment: @WilliamSun thank you for the Wikipedia Page reference it is exactly what I am looking for. Your help was really appreciated.